# Showing $\lambda I_V$ diagonalizable and has only one eigenvalue

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization, characteristic-polynomial

Problem:

> Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space, and let $\lambda$ be any scalar. For any ordered basis $\beta$ for $V$, prove that $[\lambda I_V]_{\beta}=\lambda I$. Then compute the characteristic polynomial of $\lambda I_V$ and show that $\lambda I_V$ is diagonalizable and has only one eigenvalue.

Now I proceed to compute $[\lambda I_V]_{\beta}$. I am stuck here since $V$ is not given. But I suppose $[\lambda I_V]_{\beta}=\lambda [I_V]_{\beta}=\lambda I$.

But now suppose $f_T(t)=\det ([T]_{\beta}-\lambda I_V)=1-0^n(t-\lambda)^n=(\lambda-t)^n$.

Also, note that $[\lambda I_V]_{\beta}=\lambda I$ is diagonal.

Then $\lambda I$ is diagonalizable.

Then $f_T(t)=0\implies (\lambda-t)^n=0\implies t=\lambda$.

It follows that $\lambda I$ has only one eigenvalue, which is $\lambda$.

Could anyone help me to have a look at whether my proof is legal?

Comment: sounds good to me!

Comment: $[\lambda I_V]_{\beta}$ means for each $b_i$ in the basis $\beta$, compute $\lambda I_V(b_i)$, express the result in terms of the basis $\beta$, and take the resulting coefficients as a column of $[\lambda I_V]_{\beta}$. Since $\lambda I_V(b_i)=\lambda b_i$, that matrix is $\lambda I$. You have omitted all this reasoning above. Then you introduce a new symbol, $T$, without telling anyone what it is – that can't be right.

Comment: Also, you've written $1-0^n$ where I think you meant $(1-0)^n$, and then you've gone from $(t-\lambda)^n$ to $(\lambda-t)^n$, which is not the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don’t have to suppose $[\lambda I_V]_{\beta}=\lambda [I_V]_{\beta}=\lambda I$. Let’s prove it for general case. Since $[(c\cdot T)(\alpha_j)]_B=[c\cdot T(\alpha_j)]_B=c\cdot [T(\alpha_j)]_B$, we have $[c\cdot T]_B=c\cdot [T]_B$. Matrix representation of an identity map on $V$ with respect to any ordered basis is $I_n$.

By definition, characteristic polynomial of $\lambda I_V$ is characteristic polynomial of $\lambda I$. Let $A=\lambda I$. Then characteristic polynomial of $A$ is $f_A:F\to F$ such that $f_A(t)=\text{det}(A-tI)$, $\forall t\in F$. By distributive property, $A-tI=\lambda I-tI=(\lambda-t)I$. So $\text{det}(A-tI)=\text{det}[(\lambda-t)I]$. Since $\text{det}$ is $n$-linear, we have $\text{det}[(\lambda-t)I]=(\lambda -t)^n\text{det}(I)=(\lambda -t)^n$. Thus characteristic polynomial of $\lambda I_V$ is $(\lambda -t)^n$.

I’m using following definition of diagonalizable, $T\in L(V,V)$ is diagonalizable$\iff$$\exists$ basis $B$ of $V$ such that $[T]_B$ is a diagonal matrix. Since $[\lambda I_V]_{\beta}=\lambda I$ and $\lambda I$ is diagonal matrix, we have $\lambda I_V$ is diagonalizable. It’s easy to check, $\lambda$ is the only eigenvalue of $\lambda I_V$.

Comment: Got it. Thanks!